# While converting from scss file to css file how to avoid conversion of any particular scss file into css?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

While converting from scss file to css file how to avoid conversion of any particular scss file into css?

I have 20 scss file which eventually convert to css which make css file very large. I am trying to convert only few file to css and want to avoid other.

This question may seems directly asking for solution but i have searching answer for this quite long. but found most of the doc unrelated.

Please give suggestion or direction to solve this issue.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you provide further explanation ?

Comment: @MihaiT i have explained lil more. please help if you can

Comment: how do you convert your scss to css ? where ?

Comment: @MihaiT using gulp i am converting

Comment: well i am guessing you import your scss files in a gulp task something like `gulp.task('sass', function () { return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss') });`  so then just select the scss files you want. the rest, put them in another folder

Comment: @MihaiT yes correct

Comment: So you import your scss files from a folder. Just move the ones you don't want to import into another folder :)

Answer (score 2):

Add an underscore `-` to the start of the filename. From the official [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials):

> If you have a SCSS or Sass file that you want to import but don't want to compile to a CSS file, you can add an underscore to the beginning of the filename. This will tell Sass not to compile it to a normal CSS file. You can then import these files without using the underscore.